# Why I can't display html from Summernote?

Tags: php, laravel, summernote

Hello everyone can you help me. I try to display HTML on .blade from Summernote text editor but it shows like this pic.
[image: This Pic]

Comment: Please post your code in the question. Is the image from browser or editor?

Comment: Please can you show how your trying to render this in your blade file i.e. the code from your blade file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When outputting data in blade templates, if you use double curly braces `{{ $data }}` then the variable is passed through `htmlspecialchars` to prevent potential XSS attacks. This causes HTML to be output as a literal string.

You can use `{!! $data !!}` to output data without this escaping.

Laravel's documentation describes this pretty well; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data

Do note the warning in the documentation:

> Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your application. You should typically use the escaped, double curly brace syntax to prevent XSS attacks when displaying user supplied data.